# How To Return Multiple Matching Values Based On One Or Multiple Criteria In Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there an app that will let me create an output based on selected input of text (not sum of numbers)
Help
So i am trying to create a specific output eg if I select the components of an item based on multiple options it gives me the closest output

let’s say I select sand, cement, water and it gives an output of concrete.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygegu.jpg)
tried this in excel

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$11, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($F$2, $C$2:$C$11)*COUNTIF($G$2, $D$2:$D$11), ROW($A$2:$D$11)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$D$11))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1))
```

Comment: A visual representation with sample data and expected results will help us help you here.

Comment: It is not clear what you want, could you elaborate.

Comment: so lets say you have a list of symptoms for a disease and you want to associate the symptoms with that disease so that if you input a symptom itll bring up all possible diseases and vice versa. ive included the imag in the original post @JvdV